# Timers and javafx

Tags: multithreading, timer, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to write a code that will make things appear on the screen at predetermined but irregular intervals using javafx. I tried to use a timer ([java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), not [javax.swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)) but it turns out you can't change anything in the application if you are working from a separate thread.(Like a Timer) Can anyone tell me how I could get a Timer to interact with the application if they are both separate threads?

Comment: See [How to update a label every 2 seconds in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128423/how-to-update-the-label-box-every-2-seconds-in-java-fx/16138351#16138351); i.e use [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to update UI from a seperate thread or use the [JavaFX animation framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) to keep everything on the UI thread.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you touch any JavaFX component you must do so from the Platform thread (which is essentially the event dispatch thread for JavaFX.) You do this easily by calling `Platform.runLater()`. So, for instance, it's perfectly safe to do this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //Do some stuff in another thread
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                label.update();
                javafxcomponent.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 22):

You don't need `java.util.Timer` or `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule future actions on the JavaFX application thread. You can use JavaFX Timeline as a timer:

```
new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis(2500),
        ae -> doSomething()))
    .play();
```

Alternatively, you can use a convenience method from [ReactFX](http://www.reactfx.org):

```
FxTimer.runLater(
        Duration.ofMillis(2500),
        () -> doSomething());
```

Note that you don't need to wrap the action in `Platform.runLater`, because it is already executed on the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: how do you pause and resume the ReactFX's Timer and FxTimer if using ReactFX ? I'm using it to save something periodically. Is there an equivalent pause() and play() in ReactFX, just like Timeline's pause() and play() ?

Answer (score 19):

berry120 answer works with java.util.Timer too so you can do

```
Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
         Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                label.update();
                javafxcomponent.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }
}, delay, period);
```

I used this and it works perfectly