# JavaFX not redrawing properly

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to make a cryptex program using `JavaFX`, but sometimes the rendering gets corrupted.

#### What it should be showing:

[image: This]

#### However, sometimes the rotation snags it show this:

[image: this]

Why is this happening? What can I do to fix this? I've found lots of other posts saying that JavaFX should handle all of the rendering for you, but forcing a redraw seems like the only solution, and I couldn't figure out how to do that either.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Cryptex extends Application{
    private Spool[] spools;
    private double radius = 100, perspectiveScale = 0.1;
    Stage stage;
    Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle("Criptex");

        Group root = new Group();
        scene = new Scene(root, 550, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        spools = new Spool[5];
        spools[0] = new Spool("jdkwndityc", -150);
        spools[1] = new Spool("lqhmnxfgso", -75);
        spools[2] = new Spool("usjnzuvbid", 0);
        spools[3] = new Spool("ihgkewobde", 75);
        spools[4] = new Spool("cdelsprkar", 150);
        for (Spool sp : spools){
            sp.angle = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
            root.getChildren().add(sp);
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Spool s : spools){
                    if (s.angle != 0){
                        if (Math.abs(s.distToAngle(0)) < Math.toRadians(1)){
                            System.out.println("snap");
                            s.snapToAngle(0);
                            for (Spool.Cell c : s.cells){
                                c.draw(s.angle);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            s.rotate(s.directionToAngle(0));
                            System.out.println((s.x+150)/75+1 + ": "+Math.round((s.angle/Math.PI)*180));
                            for (Spool.Cell c : s.cells){
                                c.draw(s.angle);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println("--");
            }
        }, 0, 10);
    }

    public class Spool extends Group{
        double angle;
        char[] chars;
        Image[] letters;
        int x;
        Cell[] cells;
        public Spool(String charList, int x){
            chars = charList.toCharArray();
            letters = new Image[chars.length];
            this.x = x;
            angle = 0;
            cells = new Cell[chars.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
                cells[i] = new Cell(i);
                this.getChildren().add(cells[i]);
            }
        }

        public void rotate(double distance){
            angle += Math.toRadians(distance);
            if (angle >= Math.PI*2){
                angle -= Math.PI*2;
            }
            if (angle < 0){
                angle += Math.PI*2;
            }
        }
        //TODO: check if this is way off
        public double distToAngle(double angle){
            rotate(0);
            if ((this.angle > angle && this.angle - angle > Math.PI) ||
                    (this.angle < angle && angle - this.angle > Math.PI)){
                return Math.abs(this.angle - angle);
            }
            else {
                return -Math.abs(this.angle - angle);
            }
        }
        public double closestAngle(){
            int closest = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
                if (Math.abs(distToAngle(i*((Math.PI*2)/chars.length))) 
                        < Math.abs(distToAngle(closest*((Math.PI*2)/chars.length)))){
                    closest = i;
                }
            }
            return closest;
        }
        public boolean snapToAngle(double angle){
            if (Math.abs(this.distToAngle(angle)) > Math.toRadians(1)){
                if (this.distToAngle(angle) > 0){
                    this.rotate(-1);
                }
                else {
                    this.rotate(1);
                }
                return false;
            }
            else if (this.angle != angle){
                this.angle = angle;
            }
            return true;
        }
        public double indexToAngle(int index){
            return ((Math.PI*2)/chars.length)*index;
        }
        public double perspectiveWidth(double d){
            return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(d, 2)) * perspectiveScale;
        }
        public double toAngle(int index){
            return ((Math.PI*2)/chars.length)*(index) + angle + ((Math.PI*2)/(chars.length*2));
        }
        public int directionToAngle(double angle){
            return (int) Math.signum(this.distToAngle(angle));
        }

        public class Cell extends Group {
            private int index;
            PerspectiveTransform pt = new PerspectiveTransform();
            public Cell(int index){//, double angle, Stage stage){
                this.index = index;

                Text text = new Text();
                //System.out.println("char: " + String.valueOf(chars[c]));
                text.setText(String.valueOf(chars[index]).toUpperCase());
                text.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", FontWeight.BOLD, 36));
                text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                text.setX(9);
                text.setY(32);

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(40, 40);
                rect.setFill(Color.BEIGE);
                rect.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
                rect.setStrokeWidth(3);
                rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

                this.draw(angle);
                this.setCache(true);
                this.getChildren().addAll(rect, text);  
            }

            public void draw(double angle){
                double cx = stage.getWidth()/2 + x;
                double cy = (stage.getHeight()-100)/2;
                if (cy + radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index)+angle) <= cy + radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index+1)+angle)){
                    this.setVisible(true);
                    pt.setUlx(cx - 20 - perspectiveWidth(radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index)+angle)));
                    pt.setUrx(cx + 20 + perspectiveWidth(radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index)+angle)));
                    pt.setLrx(cx + 20 + perspectiveWidth(radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index+1)+angle)));
                    pt.setLlx(cx - 20 - perspectiveWidth(radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index+1)+angle)));

                    pt.setUly(cy + radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index)+angle));
                    pt.setUry(cy + radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index)+angle));
                    pt.setLry(cy + radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index+1)+angle));
                    pt.setLly(cy + radius*Math.sin(toAngle(index+1)+angle));
                    this.setEffect(pt);
                }
                else {
                    this.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the same as [the one seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764549/timers-and-javafx), using a `java.util.Timer` directly inside JavaFX is not thread safe.

This is because [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) uses it's own background thread, but if you want to do any updates to the GUI, you need to be using the JavaFX GUI thread (a special thread JavaFX creates and handles). Trying to touch the GUI from another thread creates problems like the ones you are seeing.

You can pass changes to JavaFX `components` to the special JavaFX thread by wrapping the changes in a [`Platform.runLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) block.

The code looks like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> { //Lambda for Runnable
            for (Spool s : spools){
                if (s.angle != 0){
                    if (Math.abs(s.distToAngle(0)) < Math.toRadians(1)){
                        System.out.println("snap");
                        s.snapToAngle(0);
                        for (Spool.Cell c : s.cells){
                            c.draw(s.angle);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        s.rotate(s.directionToAngle(0));
                        System.out.println((s.x+150)/75+1 + ": "
                            + Math.round((s.angle/Math.PI)*180));
                        for (Spool.Cell c : s.cells){
                            c.draw(s.angle);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 10);
```

#### Pure JavaFX Style:

You can also use a JavaFX [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) and not have to worry about the thread issues:

```
Timeline timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis(10),
        event -> {//Same for loop as above}
));
timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timer.play();
```

Comment: For anyone that wants to have the full class with hopefully correct conventions: https://gist.github.com/Emrage/6de2c7451bc4b68f830aa6e7260a2ddd