# How to use PauseTransition method in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I read the book, but I am still confused about pause transition methods.
I made a label showing number, and I want that number to be increased in every second.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*How to use a PauseTransition*

A [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) is for a one off pause.  The following sample will update the text of a label after a one second pause:

```
label.setText("Started");
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
pause.setOnFinished(event ->
   label.setText("Finished: 1 second elapsed");
);
pause.play();
```

---

*Why a PauseTransition may not be the best answer for you*

According to your question, you want to update the label every second, not just once.

You can run a PauseTransition repetitively, see [c0der’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45559673/1155209).  This involves replaying the transition within the handler.

*You should use a Timeline*

This is my preferred solution for repetitive execution on the JavaFX thread.

As [suggested by Tomas Mikula](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2014/06/04/timers-in-javafx-and-reactfx.html), use a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) instead of a PauseTransition.

```
label.setText("Started");
final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(
        Duration.seconds(1),
        event -> {
            i.set(i.get() + 1);
            label.setText("Elapsed time: " + i.get() + " seconds");
        } 
    )
);
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

*Alternate solution with a Timer*

There is an alternate solution based on a [Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128423/how-to-update-the-label-box-every-2-seconds-in-java-fx) for the following question:

- [How to update the label box every 2 seconds in java fx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128423/how-to-update-the-label-box-every-2-seconds-in-java-fx)

However, I prefer the Timeline based solution to the Timer solution from that question.  The Timer requires a new thread and extra care in ensuring updates occur on the JavaFX application thread. The Timeline based solution does not require any of that.

---

*Not a solution: setting `cycleCount` on a pause transition*

[`pauseTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#cycleCountProperty) won’t work.  With this, the pause transition will cycle [indefinitely](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#INDEFINITE).  That won’t help you, because you can't set an event handler on cycle completion in JavaFX 17.

If a PauseTransition is cycled indefinitely, the finish handler for the transition will never be called because the transition will never finish.

---

*Related*

- [Delayed and periodic tasks with JavaFX.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task/60685975#60685975)

Comment: To be complete, you can use the PauseTransition if you start it again inside of the finish handler if I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [Adowarth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5236247/adowrath) :

> you can use the PauseTransition if you start it again inside of the
>   finish handler

```
int cycle = 0;
label.setText("Started");
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
pause.setOnFinished(event ->
   label.setText("Finished cycle " + cycle++);
   pause.play(); 
);
pause.play();
```