# how to show and hide an image for few seconds in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to show an image or a text in a label just for few seconds and then it disappear . Something like this :

```
lable.setText("data inserted");
//wait two second 
lable.setText(null);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`PauseTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html):

```
lable.setText("data inserted");
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> lable.setText(null));
pause.play();
```

Comment: More detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543619/how-to-use-pausetransition-method-in-javafx