# Java Clock Synchronizing

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have to show multiple clocks in screen from different places like New Delhi, Hong Kong, Frankfurt, Washington, etc. And these times are changing like any other real clock but as Time-Left to a fixed date-time and they are added to the screen at different moments as the user adds them. For example:

```
New Delhi       1d 4h 20 min 5s
Hong Kong       9h 2min 55s
Washington      22min 3s
...
```

I have a Class which makes all the calculations to get those times in that format. The problem comes when these times are shown on screen. How do I make them to update their time at the same time? So all the changes in the seconds are shown at the same time. I know it won't be theoretically at the same time, but the most close to it. This is the timer I am using:

```
Timer t = new Timer();   
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run() {
          Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  label[id].setText(getTimeLeft(id));
              }
          });
        }
    },
    0,      // run first occurrence immediately
    1000);  // run every seconds
```

Also, some of them freeze eventually. Does any body knows why?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {` might suggest JavaFX, BUT, you suggestion still has merit

Comment: It might be better to use a single `Timer` which is responsible for updating a list of labels instead of using multiple `Timer`s for individual labels

Comment: Gonna withdraw it as I'm out of my element here. Thanks @MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make them to update their time at the same time? So all the changes in the seconds are shown at the same time. I know it won't be theoretically at the same time, but the most close to it. This is the timer I am using:

Instead of using separate `Timer`s for each label, use a single `Timer` for ALL the labels

```
Timer t = new Timer();   
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run() {
          Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  for (int id = 0; id < label.length; id++) {
                      label[id].setText(getTimeLeft(id));
                  }
              }
          });
        }
    },
    0,      // run first occurrence immediately
    1000);  // run every seconds
```

This will reduce the overhead of resources on you system (one timer instead of n times), possible event queue spamming as multiple timers trigger simultaneously and allow the times to "seem" to update at the same time, as they are all updated within the event queue, so they won't update until the next paint cycle, which won't happen until you exit the run block...

You could also make use `Timeline`, which would reduce the need for `Platform.runLater`, see [How to update the label box every 2 seconds in java fx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128423/how-to-update-the-label-box-every-2-seconds-in-java-fx) for an example.

Comment: Yes, this approach works very well. Now the transition from one second to another is instantly, it is unnoticeable at simple sight.